# jQuery Prepending a DIV by sliding it down

Tags: jquery, css

```
$('#container').prepend("<ul><li>Stuff</li></ul>').hide().slideDown();
```

I want the NEW UL to slide Down. but the above is sliding down the entire #container..

How can I prepend an item to the top, and then slide it down.. Kinda like how Twitter used to show you your new tweet.

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can try using this syntax instead:

```
$('<ul><li>Stuff</li></ul>').prependTo('#container').hide().slideDown();
```

Of course, if you're using a list like that it might be useful to construct it element by element like this:

```
var ul = $('<ul />').prependTo('#container');
$('<li />').appendTo(ul).text('Incoming!').hide().slideDown();
```

Comment: Thanks the first one worked great. Thanks! Why construct it by element, that's more code?

Comment: @user It's not really more code in the sense that if you're going to do this for a lot of elements it quickly becomes a mess of string concatenations. The second method is useful for managing more complex stuff.

Comment: I'd make a small change and move the `.hide()` to before the prependTo/appendTo. Only to prevent any minute display before the hide (on slower JS engines)...

Comment: @Alastair Good idea, though I have to admit I've never seen that before, even on IE

Comment: @Yi Jiang: Agreed, it's not very common, but I have run into it occasionally on IE. *shakes fist at IE*